# How to solve internet check problem in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, alert, reachability, internet-connection

I am working on an application and i have to check internet connectivity. I am using two files Reachability.h and Reachability.m. Now i have to show an alert when internet is not working.

But when my observer check the internet it shows alert view more then one time. and some times it shows the alert more 9-10 times.
my code is here:

in .h file

```
Reachability* internetReachable;
    Reachability* hostReachable;
    NetworkStatus internetStatus;
```

in .m file

```
        internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
        [internetReachable startNotifier];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
        hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
        [hostReachable startNotifier];



- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice    
     {
        internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];

        if (internetStatus != NotReachable){
            NSLog(@"internet is on");

        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Server not connected or down!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            internetCount++;
        }           
}
```

this code is in delegate and similarly i am using this code in other classes where ever i have to check internet

plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Reachability because I've had problems like you, so I created my own implementation. Just import the header file below and then call `[self networkIsReachable]` to check for an internet connection.

```
    #import <netinet/in.h>
    - (BOOL)networkIsReachable 
    {
        struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
        bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
        zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
        zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

        SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&zeroAddress);
        SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
        BOOL gotFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags);
        CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability);
        if (!gotFlags) {
            return NO;
        }
        BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable;

        BOOL noConnectionRequired = !(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired);
        if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)) {
            noConnectionRequired = YES;
        }

        return (isReachable && noConnectionRequired) ? YES : NO;
    }
```

Comment: No, as I said, you just need to add `#import <netinet/in.h>` to your `.h` file.

Comment: but it is giving some error that "SCNetworkReachabilityRef is undeclared"

Comment: try importing the `SystemConfiguration` framework if you haven't done so already. (that's what `SC` stands for)

Comment: ok i have imported it and errors are removed but how it will detect if internet is turned off while running application?

Comment: Did you read my answer at all? I already said that you can check it via `[self networkIsReachable]`. Read the Apple Documentation if you don't know how to use a method.

Comment: @DavidSchiefer thanks for share this code. I call this method with `[self networkIsReachable]` and is okay. You suggest to call that method before any request? What happens if the connection is UP, the request starts and the connection go DOWN? Ty.

Comment: It depends how you've structured your app. I check for a connection on startup and that's it because my methods will relay failures to my delegate if there's no connection later on. What do you mean with UP?